# Non-zero exit status 1, when using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm creating my first Flask API. I'm using recasepunc model.

This is my code:

```
import subprocess

text = "Hello"
cased = subprocess.check_output('python recasepunc/recasepunc.py predict recasepunc/checkpoint', shell=True, text=True, input=text)
return cased
```

I get the error:
**python recasepunc/recasepunc.py predict recasepunc/checkpoint' returned non-zero exit status 1**

I've already checked, if I installed all the requirements. I don't know, what else I can do.

Comment: What happens when you run that command outside of Python (not using `subprocess`)? As in running `recasepunc/recasepunc.py predict recasepunc/checkpoint` on the terminal/shell directly?

Comment: Your subprocess command is written in a way that depends on what directory it's run from. Did you check if it's being run from the right directory?

Comment: I tried to run this command without subprocess and it gives 'RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.60 GiB already allocated; 6.20 MiB free; 2.74 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Comment: It happens when I use last version of transformers. When I use transformers ==4.10.0 (it's written in the requierements), I receive: 'AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'Trie' on <module 'transformers.tokenization_utils' from '...Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\transformers\\tokenization_utils.py'>'

Comment: Seems like a CUDA problem, not a Python problem (but just in case, make sure you are pointing to the checkpoint correctly, it is often easy to go one level too shallow/too deep). Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/72431190/10672371: it could be a driver issue, in which case - my condolences. Is this the first run of pytorch or, indeed, CUDA-powered models, in your environment?

Comment: Apparently it worked with transformers==4.16.2.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the working comment of the owner of the question:

"transformers==4.16.2" really worked!

```
pip install transformers==4.16.2
```