# CUDA Runtime Error during Spacy Transformers NER Model Training

Tags: python, gpu, spacy, huggingface-transformers

I am currently training a custom NER model (having 90k data records), using Spacy Transformers (en_core_web_trf) and I'm encountering an issue where the training process is taking an unusually long time and eventually gets killed, throwing a CUDA runtime error.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

```
Model: Custom NER model
Library: Spacy Transformers
Hardware: I'm using AWS ec2 sever (g4dn.8xlarge) vCPUs : 32 GB,
Software: Python version 3.6.9, spacy version 3.6.1
The error message I'm receiving is:
"RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 114.00 MiB (GPU 0; 14.76 GiB total capacity; 11.19 GiB already allocated; 78.75 MiB free; 12.40 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF"
```

I've tried a few troubleshooting steps such as checking GPU memory usage, killing processes that might be engaging GPU memory, and adjusting batch sizes, but the issue persists.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try few options

**Make small batch sizes until the error vanishes**

Clear the cache by:

```
import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

or

```
import gc
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

then again try reducing batch size.

Comment: this i tried, didn't worked...

Comment: please can you share your example? I believe it should work.

Comment: explain is that i've a custom data around 95k+ records, and i've created train.spacy file and while training it's giving errors, CUDA out of memory, even i've tried a lot of thigs, but nothing works, many peoples are facing the same issues, while training spacy model on GPU

Comment: @iamhimanshu0 I came across multiple questions about `"RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory.` in every question they are asking to reduce the batch size. I will attach reference for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54376403/13086128 ; https://stackoverflow.com/a/62556666/13086128; https://stackoverflow.com/a/72433191/13086128; https://stackoverflow.com/a/73350182/13086128; https://medium.com/@snk.nitin/how-to-solve-cuda-out-of-memory-error-850bb247cfb2